# Mock Linking.openURL in React Native it's never been called

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-hooks, react-hooks-testing-library

I´m writing some tests for my app and I´m trying to mock `Linking` module. I'm using `jest`.
The `Linking.canOpenURL` mock it's working fine (`toHaveBeenCalled` is returning `true`), but `openURL` mock is never called.

```
    function mockSuccessLinking() {
      const canOpenURL = jest
        .spyOn(Linking, 'canOpenURL')
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));
      const openURL = jest
        .spyOn(Linking, 'openURL')
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));

      return { canOpenURL, openURL };
    }
```

The problem is that `openURL` is not been called.

Here is the test:

```
test('should open url when there is a proper app the open it', async () => {
      const { canOpenURL, openURL } = mockSuccessLinking();
      const { result } = renderHook(() =>
         useApplyToJob('https://www.google.com/'),
      );
      const [apply] = result.current;

      // Act
      apply();

      // Assert
      expect(result.current[1].error).toBeNull();
      expect(canOpenURL).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(openURL).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And this the hook under test:

```
export function useApplyToJob(url) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const apply = () => {
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(url);
      } else {
        setError(`Don't know how to open ${url}`);
      }
    });
  };

  return [apply, { error }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `canOpenURL` returns a promise, you'll need to wait for the async to occur before testing if `openURL` has been called. `react-hooks-testing-library` ships a few [async utils](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#async-utilities) to help with this.

Generally it's preferred to use `waitForNextUpdate` or `waitForValueToChange` as they are a bit more descriptive of what the test is waiting for, but your hook is not updating any state in the successful case, so you will need to use the more general `waitFor` utility instead:

```js
test('should open url when there is a proper app the open it', async () => {
      const { canOpenURL, openURL } = mockSuccessLinking();
      const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() =>
         useApplyToJob('https://www.google.com/'),
      );
      const [apply] = result.current;

      // Act
      apply();

      // Assert
      expect(result.current[1].error).toBeNull();
      expect(canOpenURL).toHaveBeenCalled();

      await waitFor(() => {
          expect(openURL).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
});
```

As a side note, destructuring `result.current` to access `apply` is not recommended.  It may work now, but it does not take much refactoring before the `apply` you're calling is using stale values from a previous render.

Similarly, I'd recommend wrapping the `apply()` call in `act`, even though it does not update any state right now.  It just makes refactoring easier in the future as well as keeping your tests more consistent when you're testing the error case (which will need an `act` call).

```js
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

// ...

test('should open url when there is a proper app the open it', async () => {
      const { canOpenURL, openURL } = mockSuccessLinking();
      const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() =>
         useApplyToJob('https://www.google.com/'),
      );

      // Act
      act(() => {
        result.current[0]();
      });

      // Assert
      expect(result.current[1].error).toBeNull();
      expect(canOpenURL).toHaveBeenCalled();

      await waitFor(() => {
          expect(openURL).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'ts working fine now!